# A program that allow the user to have their stats created using a dice rolling method

Tags: python, random

**A program that allow the user to have their stats created using a dice rolling method.**

need to create a program which allows a user to have their stats created using a dice rolling method. It has to create 2 different stats, a Strength attribute, and a Skill Atribute. For these to be created it has a 12 sided dice rolled, and a 4 sided dice rolled. The value of the 12 sided dice is then divided by the 4 sided dice for the Strength Attribute, this is then repeated for the Skill Attribute. That's all, I'm not sure where to go about with this and any help would be thanked very much.

heres what ive done so far. but the "random.random" does not work i could not understand why it didnt work,also would you be able to assign the twelve sided dice and the four sided dice.

```
import random

for i in range(5):

# random float: 0.0 <= number < 1.0
    print random.random(0,0) * 100,

# random float: 10 <= number < 20
    print random.uniform(10, 20),

# random integer: 100 <= number <= 1000
    print random.randint(100, 1000),

# random integer: even numbers in 100 <= number < 1000
    print random.randrange(100, 1000, 2)
```

thanks

Comment: And the error message didn't tell you anything about what might be wrong?

Comment: What do you think `TypeError: random() takes no arguments (2 given)` might mean? You are calling `random.random(0,0)`, passing in 2 arguments. Why do you pass in two arguments?

Comment: This same question was just asked by another user; this same example of the random module exists on [effbot](http://effbot.org/librarybook/random.htm) Did you make another user to ask the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076272/need-to-create-dice-roller-which-determines-a-characters-stats/20076440#comment29911865_20076440)? Or are you in the same class with the first poster? Maybe get together and discuss then post your work here?

Comment: Except the effbot example doesn't pass any arguments to `random.random`.  :)

Comment: @SilasRay Ssshh! 'Learning in progress!' ;)

Answer (score 0):

This URL may help you understand what's wrong with random.random(0, 0) :

http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.random

Here's what I suspect you're looking for:

```
print float(random.randint(1, 12)) / random.randint(1, 4)
```